# SOAPUI Rest service error

Tags: java, rest, soapui

I have a Jersey Rest service running on Glassfish. When I test my service from Firefox by simply typing the URL, I can GET the expected result as json on browser.

I wanted to test the same method using the SOAPUI but then I get a 404 page not found error. I even dont know where should I start looking for the problem. Is that possible that my service is wrongly configured, Or I have to tweak some SoapUI settings in order to make it work. I just give it the WADL url and then simply run the "Request1"

Comment: Are you binding the rest service to specific headers (eg content-type or accept)?

Comment: @Qwerky  yes i do, but i set them in soapui

Comment: 404 is not expected even if some headers are missing. try rest client in firebox, what it says. are you running on same machine?

Comment: @sudmong works well on rest clients plugings

Comment: then it must be due to some wrong setting in soapui. don't remember the settings, used it long back.

Answer (score 1):

Please to be sure that you have pointed correctly to the rest service look this:
http://www.joecolantonio.com/2012/09/05/soapui-how-to-test-a-rest-service/
I've tested and works.

Remember that you must add the declaration of the web service in the web.xml file.